# Cannot make a get request from the back end to google's Query Suggestion Service

Tags: java, get-request, google-suggest

Why can't I make a get request from the back end to google's Query Suggestion Service using Java?

I want to make a get request to this service [Google: Query Suggestion Service /suggest Protocol](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/query_suggestion.html).

so that I can get a response which would list suggested queries. It seems like this library is only for front end javascript applications though because there is a paramater 'client' which needs to be provided. If I set it to chrome and make the request via chrome it works fine. But if I try and make the request using the default in java I don't get anything back.

If this is not possible is there any other tool that does a similar task?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to set my User-Agent to the same as my browser using the setRequestProperty and it worked.